# Open source ad stats not updating

Tags: bug, status-completed, open-source-advertising

The [ads stat page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/74983) doesn't seem to be updated. Only a couple of ads have stats ( active for, impressions etc ) , but those have been at the '4 days' level for at least 3 days.

Most ads haven't registered any impressions yet.

Comment: We're aware of it and are looking into it. (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scheduled task was running under an account without proper permissions; fixed.

Comment: The link is actually dead now...

Comment: @TryPyPy - should be all good now.

Comment: What now? The stats page only shows a single ad for me now.

Comment: @Franz http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/74983 should be the corrected link to view all ads